# Mongoose Populate on Save

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to save a model and populate the Dbref-like field within the saved model.

I'm currently doing

```
dbrefobj.findbyid(id).run(
    function (err, dbrefobj) {
        topobj.save....
```

I would like to do something like

```
topobj.save.populate(dbrefobj)
```

Thanks!

Comment: depending on the library you're using, there could / (should?) be pre-save handlers for this stuff. Check yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `'save'` middleware in your schema to insert your own processing into the act of saving a document.  In your case you'd look up the referenced document and pull in whatever you need from that into the document being saved.  See the Mongoose middleware docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).